# How to list objects in many to many Django

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

Considerer this model

```
class Dealership(models.Model):
    dealership = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Ordered(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer")
    dealership = models.ManyToManyField("Dealership")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=status_list, default='p')
```

I try

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from new_way.core.models import Ordered, Dealership
>>> q = Ordered.objects.all()[:5]
>>> [i.dealership for i in q.dealership.all]
```

And generate error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'dealership'
```

How to return

```
Ordered.dealership.dealership
```

all dealership by Ordered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're very close:

Change:

```
[i.dealership for i in q.dealership.all]
```

to:

```
[dealership for dealership in q.dealership.all()]
```

Here's sample output from one of my model's M2M relationships on a project which demonstrates what you should see from the list comprehension. `shared_with` is an M2M field to a model called `Profile`:

```
>>> from polls.models import Poll
>>> polls = Poll.objects.all()
>>> for p in polls:
...   print([sw for sw in p.shared_with.all()])
... 
[<Profile: kerri>]
[<Profile: kerri>]
[]
[<Profile: jake>, <Profile: kerri>]
[<Profile: jake>, <Profile: kerri>]
[<Profile: jake>, <Profile: kerri>]
[<Profile: btaylor>]
[<Profile: jake>, <Profile: kerri>]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'dealership'

Comment: [x for x in Ordered().__dict__.keys()]
['modified_at', 'created_at', 'kiosk_id', '_state', 'vehicle_id', 'kit_optional_id', 'customer_id', 'status', 'id']

Comment: dealership no exists. But _state exists.

Comment: The above code should give you a list of `Dealership` instances. I'm not understanding what you're referring to in your previous comment.

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
q.dealership.all() #gives a list of objects
```

You can directly do this instead of using list comprehension(in the above ans).

**Example:** (Taken from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/))

```
from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

Create a couple of Publications:

```
p1 = Publication(title='The Python Journal')
p1.save()
p2 = Publication(title='Science News')
p2.save()
p3 = Publication(title='Science Weekly')
p3.save()
```

Now, create an `Article` and the associate the `Article` with a `Publication`:

```
a1 = Article(headline='NASA uses Python')
a1.save()
a1.publications.add(p1, p2)
a1.publications.add(p3)

a1.publications.all()
[<Publication: Science News>, <Publication: Science Weekly>, <Publication: The Python Journal>]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'dealership'